# Image Popup box with jquery

Tags: jquery, image, web, popup, load

I have created a dropdown menu which holds different cities. Now I would like to be able to select a city and an image of the city should appear in a pop up box. I have a website that holds an image of each city and the urls only slightly differ from each other. Does anybody know how to write the function for this with jquery? 
Thanks in advance for every answer :)

Comment: What have you done so far? Did you try to achieve this in any ways?

Comment: I have never used jquery bevor so I don't really know how to do it. I have created an ajax request that loads cityinformation from a json file into my dropdown menu. Now I need to write a function that gets called whenever the ajax request was successful that lets me click on a city, opens a pop up box and loads an image from a website. But I don't really know the syntax for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a hidden div that would pop up when you click on city.

something along these lines:

```
<div class="imgHolder">
    <img src="">
</div>
```

click on city would make popup show up:

```
$('.city').click(function(){

    $('.imgHolder').children("img").attr("src", var_image_path)
    $('.imgHolder').show();

});
```

something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/EMLH3/

i've left the styling part to you, but the basics are in the fiddle.

Comment: Wow awesome!!! 
Is there a way that I can use a variable in the url of the images? Like "htp://citiesoftheworld/" +cityname+ ".png" I'm loading all images from the same website and just have to switch around the citynames.

Comment: Well you need to link the selections with images and I think the solution I provided is the easiest - changing the whole src path to the image. I'd need to see the actual code (html) for (possible) easier solution.